# Proof for determinants

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, determinant

Say matrix B is obtained by some reordering of the columns on matrix A. Then det(B) = - det(A).

If you switch 2 columns it is true, but if you switch 3 columns its false. I'm not sure how to generalize a formal odd/even proof for this?

Comment: Every time you switch the determinant changes sign. Look at the cycles in your switching permutation.

Comment: This is false with “some” reordering, because you can only say that $\lvert\det(B)\rvert=\lvert\det(A)\rvert$: think to the reordering that moves no column. It is true for those reorderings that are obtained by an odd number of switches.

Comment: I understand that, but I'm not sure how to explicitly prove that without hand waving arguments

Comment: If you're comfortable with the fact that switching ONE PAIR of columns gives a minus sign, then any re-ordering (permutation) of columns can be obtained from a sequence of switches, where 2 columns are swapped at each step (this is the fact that the symmetric group is generated by transpositions). Then if $n$ is the number of such swaps, then $\mathrm{det}(B) = (-1)^n \mathrm{det}(A)$. This is essentially what copper.hat is saying in the comment above.